# Get schema name of specific field in list

Tags: column, spservices

How to get Schema name of specific field in a SharePoint list?

I'm using SPservices to get list items from the list but one field is missing in the result. I want all field values of the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a external tool (u2u Caml builder, Query Helper,..) to list all fields and see their internal names

https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/ - Query Helper download